# How can I travel to USA with an old passport that has the visa?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, indian-citizens

I got an American Visa (10 years Visa) in 2014, and my passport expired in 2018. Although I've renewed my passport, the visa stamp is on the old passport.

Does the immigration at the New York Airport require a Visa Stamp? Or would it be alright if they could scan the new passport and get visa details that are stamped on my old passport.

Cause I guess, the stamp is probably not required now days when everything is digital, and maybe I could travel with only my renewed passport.

Just curious, cause I kind of kept my old passport in a safe place and don't remember where it is anymore.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Traveling to the US with new passport, visa on the old one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36589/traveling-to-the-us-with-new-passport-visa-on-the-old-one)

Comment: @aland that question is asking whether it's possible to use both passports together (to which the answer is "yes"), while this one is asking if it's possible to use the valid visa in the old passport without actually bringing it with you, showing only the new passport (to which the answer is "no").  So this question is not the same as that one.

Comment: I love the bit about how you were so worried about keeping it safe that you lost it :-)

Comment: You can enter US provided you present the new passport and the old one which has valid US Visa. In my case it has happened precisely like that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You must present the visa at the immigration desk.  This means that you must bring both your old (invalid) passport with the valid visa and your new valid passport.  If you cannot find the old passport, you will need to apply for a new visa.  See for example [About Visas - The Basics](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html) at the website of the US State Department:

> **My old passport has already expired. My visa to travel to the United States is still valid but in my expired passport. Do I need to apply for a new visa with my new passport?**
>
> No. If your visa is still valid you can travel to the United States with your two passports, as long as the visa is valid, not damaged, and is the appropriate type of visa required for your principal purpose of travel. (Example: tourist visa, when your principal purpose of travel is tourism). Both passports (the valid and the expired one with the visa) should be from the same country and type (Example: both Uruguayan regular passports, both official passports, etc.). When you arrive at the U.S. port-of-entry (POE, generally an airport or land border) the Customs and Border Protection Immigration Officer will check your visa in the old passport and if s/he decides to admit you into the United States they will stamp your new passport with an admission stamp along with the annotation "VIOPP" (visa in other passport). Do not try to remove the visa from your old passport and stick it into the new valid passport. If you do so, your visa will no longer be valid.

While it is true that the technology exists to check your visa without actually having the sticker in hand, US immigration law hasn't adapted to that reality.  Furthermore, the airline will not even allow you to board the plane unless you can show the visa.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue of "adapting to that reality". Without requiring a physical visa, if a country has lax passport security, somebody can get a fake passport made and enter the US on that. The US, on the other hand, has control of their physical visas and their security features. Thus, somebody has to be able to fake a passport and fake the US visa to get in.

Comment: @user71659 as visas are stored in a database, a fake passport would have to match the name and number of the passport of someone else who has actually been granted a visa. And the person would have to match the photograph on the visa (and in most cases the fingerprints of the visa applicant), for those are stored as well. This seems rather more difficult than forging a visa sticker, though admittedly it's harder to do all of that and forge a visa sticker than just to do all of that.

Comment: Some countries punch a hole through (all the pages of) the expired passport before handing out the new one. I wonder if a visa will be considered "damaged" in this case.

Comment: @user71659 if that was the case countries would not be stopping issuing physical visas, but [they are](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/110196/17015).

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Most countries (if not all) consider such a visa to have been invalidated.  But every cancelled passport I've seen has had only the cover and identification page punched or clipped, leaving the visa pages intact.  I understand however that some countries ask you to notify them that you have valid visas that you want to preserve, so I suppose these countries normally cancel all of the pages.

Comment: @phoog Dutch authorities punch all pages, punching holes about 1cm in diameter through the 4 corners. Not sure how large a US visa is (not seen one in decades) but may well be that it isn't affected.

Comment: @jwenting I have several cancelled Dutch passports and they are not punched as you describe. They have two large holes punched through the corners, and they were folded back on themselves so the front and back covers could be punched along with the ID page without damaging the visa pages.  A US visa is a standard-sized full-page sticker.

Comment: @phoog 4 holes is how all mine were ever punched, and the ones my father had as well that he needed to keep. Maybe different cities do it differently.

Comment: @phoog last time I kept my old passport the holes were stamped pretty much through the middle, like here: https://d16junmm04ri2h.cloudfront.net/image/lg/pictures/131227_paspoort_met_gat_ongeldig_6807722566871FFCC1257C4D005FB83B.jpg or here: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-hH4YUEnM7nQ/VMVPHt-yXhI/AAAAAAAAAb8/6mxwL58twuI/s1600/IMG_2848%5B1%5D.JPG

Comment: @jwenting I just checked my passports. There are three holes, not two as I had remembered, but they are indeed only in the covers and ID pages, except for one with holes in the covers, the ID page, and the last page before the back cover. These were cancelled in the consulate general in New York (or in whatever office handles consular applications, which I believe these days are done in the Netherlands).

Comment: @CompuChip mine have all been punched so the machine readable zone at the bottom of the ID page is partly affected.  That is, at least two of the three holes are within a couple of centimeters of the outside edge of the book.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh The US is a high profile target. There's still countries that use ink stamps for visas.